# How to map the 2 different record set one by one?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let' say I have 2 sql queries. Table A contains,

```
ID
--
1
1
1
2
3
4
```

This query,

```
Select distinct ID1 FROM A
```

gives me,

```
ID
--
1
2
3
4
```

Second one

```
Select ID2 FROM B
```

which gives me,

```
ID2
--
8
21
33
43
```

How 2 get this record set?

```
ID1  ID2
---  ---
 1    8
 2    21
 3    33
 4    43
```

Comment: is there any relation between this two tables????

Comment: Neither of your selects has an `ORDER BY` clause, so the rows for either result could be in any order. Are we merely to randomly pair rows from `A` and `B`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, This is just a sample. I have complex queries which have ORderby caluse

Comment: The existence of that `ORDER BY` is kind of the relationship that I think Salil was looking for - we specifically need to know that these results *are* ordered, and that row 5 from one result should pair with row 5 from the other result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not specify what version of sql server but if you are using sql server 2008+, one way that you can do this is by adding the `row_number()` to each table and then joining on the `row_number()`:

```
select a.id, b.id2
from
(
  select id, row_number() over(order by id) rn
  from a
) a
inner join
(
  select id2, row_number() over(order by id2) rn
  from b
) b
  on a.rn = b.rn
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1220c/1)

If you want to only use `DISTINCT` values, then you should be able to use:

```
select a.id, b.id2
from
(
  select id, row_number() over(order by id) rn
  from
  (
    select distinct id
    from a
  ) a
) a
inner join
(
  select id2, row_number() over(order by id2) rn
  from b
) b
  on a.rn = b.rn;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3da07/9)

If you have a different number of rows in each table, then you might want to use a `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
select a.id, b.id2
from
(
  select id, row_number() over(order by id) rn
  from
  (
    select distinct id
    from a
  ) a
) a
full outer join
(
  select id2, row_number() over(order by id2) rn
  from b
) b
  on a.rn = b.rn;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bf199/1)

Comment: What if I have distinct in first SQL?

Comment: @user960567 what do you mean? If one recordset has fewer records than the other?

Comment: NO. But I have one sql with always distict

Comment: @user960567 it should still work see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cceab/1

Comment: No, The problem is that I have to select distinct IDs to make the row numbers equal to each other. You can say that first one contain 1,1,1,2,3,4 and second one 23,24,25,26

Comment: @user960567 see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3da07/6 -- do these do what you are asking?

Comment: @user960567 see my edit, the second query should do what you are asking.